# modify frame border width using script

Tags: framemaker

I'm trying to write a script file for FrameMaker that creates a keyboard shortcut for a frame border. Everything works fine except for the BorderWidth attribute:

```
aframe.Pen = 0;
aframe.Color = "Black";
aframe.BorderWidth = 0.5;
```

I want to set the border width to 0.5pt but it always comes out as 1pt. 
How can I make the border thinner using this script?

Answer (score 0):

In framemaker 1 pt is equal to 65536.
By setting 0.5, youve set it to a value lower than the minimum, so it defaults to 1 pt.

To get the desired result, set BorderWidth to 65536/2.